# PHPExcel get friendly name from hyperlink?

Tags: php, excel, hyperlink, phpexcel

I have a hyperlink in an excel sheet as follows.

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:abc@def.com","abc@def.com")
```

I've seen plenty of examples about how to extract the URL from the hyperlink using:

```
$cell->getUrl();
```

But what I can't seem to figure out is how to get the friendly name or the second part of the hyperlink which in this case would be:

> abc@def.com

I've tried getting the tooltip as well but to no avail.
I'm probably over thinking it so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hyperlink was populated using PHPExcel's own functionality, or defined directly as a hyperlink in the original spreadsheet, then

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('C17')->getHyperlink();
```

would return a PHPExcel hyperlink object, and that has methods for both `getUrl()` and `getTooltip()`

You can test if a cell contains a hyperlink before calling this method using:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('C17')->hasHyperlink();
```

Note that the tooltip is the text displayed in a small pop-up when you hover the mouse over that cell.... the actual "friendly" value is normally just the cell value that you'd retrieve using

```
$friendlyText = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('C17')->getValue();
```

---

However, when using the MS Excel HYPERLINK() function only creates a hyperlink object when that function is executed (so calling `hasHyperlink()` won't return true), and the "raw" content of the cell is the formula, so `getValue()` will return that formula rather than the "friendly" text. To get the link itself, you need to execute that formula:

```
$hyperlink = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('C17')->getCalculatedValue();
```

This returns a PHPExcel hyperlink object, but it currently contains only the Url, and not the tooltip; although I have just pushed a change to the 1.8 branch on github that will populate the tooltip as well when the formula is calculated

Comment: Using `getCalculatedValue()` returned the friendly name.

Comment: what if i want hyperlink for whole column instead of friendly name ? not for particular cell